# How to redirect on submitting a form?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with redirect.I am developing a web application in spring mvc and using ModelAndView to forword on new page or Home page.

1.when I submit the form modelAndView is forwarding to new page but url is not getting change.

```
public ModelAndView processForm(@ModelAttribute("registerForm")EmpRegistrationForm registerForm,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
    {
        registerForm = (EmpRegistrationForm) model.get("registerForm");

        ModelAndView model1= new ModelAndView(GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE);
        model=super.execute(model);

        EmpRegisterWorker worker=new EmpRegisterWorker();
        boolean status=worker.validateUser(registerForm);
        if(status)
        {
            return new ModelAndView(GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ModelAndView(GlobalConstants.ERROR_PAGE);
        }
```

2.If I refresh that page,form is getting submit twice which is not desirable.

3.I have to click back twice or thrice to go back to new page.

4.I have created GlobalConstants class where I declared all the forms like:

```
public static final String ERRORPAGE="errorPage";
    public static final String HOME_PAGE="homePage";
```

Is there any way to solve this issue.

Comment: you want to redirect to page using spring api ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, change your method return type to String and prefix your view with redirect:

```
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("registerForm")EmpRegistrationForm    registerForm,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
{
    registerForm = (EmpRegistrationForm) model.get("registerForm");

    ModelAndView model1= new ModelAndView(GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE);
    model=super.execute(model);

    EmpRegisterWorker worker=new EmpRegisterWorker();
    boolean status=worker.validateUser(registerForm);
    if(status)
    {
        return "redirect:"+GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE;
    }
    else
    {
        return "redirect:"+GlobalConstants.ERROR_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Comment: ,I have tried your answer but it is not working,Now an error I am getting like:The requested resource (/HRportal/homePage) is not available.  Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Whats your Spring Dispatcher Servlet mapping in web.xml?
You should include it also, I mean: if its mapped   <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern> then the redirect should look like this: return "redirect:/action/"+GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE;

Comment: servlet mapping is <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> the it will become "redirect:login.do/"+GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE .right?

Comment: Ok, try with return "redirect:"+GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE+".do";

Answer (score 1):

Just use `"redirect:"` string. Something like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/yourPage.htm");
```

Or just change your method to `String` return type and do:

```
return "redirect:/yourPage.htm";
```